# Gogs API jquery access allow origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, gogs

I am using the [postman](https://github.com/dnbard/brackets-postman) rest client on [Brackets](http://brackets.io).
Using that client I can request the Gogs api.
But if I want to request it using jquery I get a:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/v1/repos/.../.../issues?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is my js code:

```
     var request = $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl+'repos/.../.../issues?token='+token,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true
    });

    request.done(function( data ) {
      resolve('it works', data);
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        reject(jqXHR, textStatus);
    });
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Edit:**
At the moment it is only for developement. Therefore I can use this Chrome extension: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related)

Comment: Have you thought of JSONP ? https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/